# Improve LINQ query performance

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Assuming there is a class

```
public class StopTime
{
    public TimeSpan? ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public string StopID { get; set; }
    public int StopSequence { get; set; }
    public string TripID { get; set; }
}
```

I have to read data from a CSV file and map it to the mentioned class. The CSV file can have many records, in my case about 500000 records.

After I parse CSV file and map data to list of `StopTime` in different functions I want to filter `StopTimes` based on `TripId`.
In my scenario I've about 8000 `TripId`s in the list of `StopTime`.

I have tried to create a Dictionary of a list using this code:

```
var TripIdStops = new Dictionary<string, List<StopTime>>();

foreach (var tripId in ListOfTripId)
{
    TripIdStops.Add(tripId, StopTimes.Where(x=>x.TripID==tripsDistinct).ToList());
}
```

To create the dictionary, this loop has to filter `StopTime`s, remember 500000 records and 8000 instances of TripIds.

However, this is a very time consuming task. Is there a way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var stopTimesByTripId = StopTimes.ToLookup(st => st.TripId);
```

Or to narrow it down by `ListOfTripId` first:

```
var tripIdSet = new HashSet<string>(ListOfTripId);
var stopTimesByTripId = StopTimes.Where(st => tripIdSet.Contains(st.TripId))
                                 .ToLookup(st => st.TripId);
```

In both cases you'll only need to iterate through `StopTimes` once.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) table instead.

> Represents a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values.

```
var lookup = StopTimes.ToLookup(st => st.TripId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've suggested loop changing: go through `StopTimes`, something
like this:

```
var TripIdStops = new Dictionary<string, List<StopTime>>();

foreach (var time in StopTimes) {
  List<StopTime> list;

  if (TripIdStops.TryGetValue(time.TripID, out list))
    list.Add(time);
  else
    TripIdStops.Add(time.TripID, new List<StopTime>() { time });
}
```